# xsl return the dynamic node value

Tags: xslt

hello: 
    do you guys know how to display the nodes' value which the nodes name are dynamic,  for example, the nodes name is like x1, x2, x3...  the number 1, 2 ,3 depends on the returns of the table.

i can get the node name using the loop,  but only can get the name, even xsl:value-of select="$nodename", returns the nodename, not the value

Comment: You forgot to provide *any* essential information.

Comment: @Dimitre: Yes, without information, there is no much to say except "use `name()`".

Answer (score 1):

As @Dimitre said, you haven't given us much specific information to work with, but in general you can use this to select elements whose names are determined at run time:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = $someDynamicValue]" />
```

You can also use name(), but local-name() ignores the namespace prefix, which usually makes things easier.

If you'd like more detailed help, please provide your sample input XML (especially the "returns of the table"), and the XSLT you've tried so far; and preferably, a sample of desired output XML.